# Querying on relationship arrays in Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, relationship, realm

Lets say I have a `Dog` and `Person` realm objects like

```
@interface Dog : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSInteger age;

@property RLMArray<Person> *owners;

@end

@implementation Dog

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Dog)

@interface Person : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;
@property RLMArray<Dog> *dogs;

@end

@implementation Person

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Person)
```

This is the sample code from Realm's example project. The only difference is that `Dog` entity has an array of `Person` objects as `owners`, in other words an inverse relationship to `Person`'s `dogs`.

Now the thing I want to accomplish is querying the `Dog` objects having a `Person` as one of the `owners`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just have to do `[Dog objectsWhere:@"ANY owners = %@", person]`, where `person` is the owner you want to query for.

A complete example:

```
@protocol Person;

@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property NSInteger age;

@property RLMArray<Person> *owners;
@end

@implementation Dog
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Dog)

@interface Person : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property RLMArray<Dog> *dogs;
@end

@implementation Person
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Person)

void test() {
    RLMRealm *realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm;

    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    Person *person = [Person createInRealm:realm withObject:@{@"name": @"Tim"}];

    Dog *dog = [Dog createInRealm:realm withObject:@{@"name": @"Rover", @"age": @5, @"owners": @[person]}];
    [Dog createInRealm:realm withObject:@{@"name": @"Rex", @"age": @10, @"owners": @[]}];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

    RLMArray *dogs = [Dog objectsWhere:@"ANY owners = %@", person];
    assert(dogs.count == 1);
    assert([dog isEqual:dogs[0]]);
}
```